# How to create iOS screen dynamic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, autolayout

How I can create an iOS layout that changes dynamically. Let's say that I want create a screen like this :-

[image: Screen for Individual]

By default this screen is for individual users but when I tap on company button Ui should change to this

[image: Screen for Company]

I know I can hide textbox, textarea by coding but I dont know how make them appear in between the other control and save button and change the position of the save button automatically and this should work in all screen size and landscape and potrait mode. I don't how to explain more and search for this problem

Comment: @rmaddy why you remove the swift and objective-c tag it may require coding also

Comment: So you think it can be done without any coding in either language ?

Comment: You are making me more confuse

Answer (score 0):

Place "Company Name" and "Company Address" fields in a View. This container view of those two fields will have a constraint where the "Save" button is always below it and the "Individual" and "company" buttons are above it.

In the code for the ViewController of this view, override `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. In here you can put the logic that if Company is selected then the container view mentioned earlier is a certain height and the "Company Name" and "Company Address" feels are made hidden=false and their sizes and position are changed according to the container view's dimensions and position

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that you should make IBOutlets to the container view and the Company Name and Company Address fields within the ViewController. Now for the example code:

Example code in Swift:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if companyButtonPressed {
        var newFrame = containerView.frame
        newFrame.size.height = 600// or something

        containerView.frame = newFrame
    }
}
```

There's other ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. Like subclassing the container view and overriding drawRect instead. Explorer and discover for yourself.

Comment: please can you explain it with code, I only understand that I have to place  "Company Name" and "Company Address" fields in a View that I can do but may be I can try set constraint as you said but don't know anything about  `override viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @VarunNaharia See the edit. I think that you can put some constraints on the subviews of the container view too and just hide them by using containerView.clipsToBounds = true and setting containerView.height to 0. That way you don't have to do any calculations for the company fields.